# Generating (a b i) with two distinct 3 cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose two distinct three cycles $x, y \in S_4$ such that $x \neq y^{-1}$.
And, I am struggling to show if each of $(a b 1), (a b 2), (a b 3), (a b 4)$ such that $a \neq b$ can be generated by the multiples of x and y.

It seems possible but am struggling.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what do the dots mean?

Comment: oh i guess there is no need for dots actually. it's edited now @JonMarkPerry